# How to use one class view table for two controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers `A,B` in storyboard with the same class `CustomTableViewController` for TableViewController element.

There are standard delegates for tables in this class like as:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
```

In the method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {// Load data for A and B controllers }
```

How I can rule this class for two controllers?
For example, if I open view controller A, class must be load data A, else load data B.

Problem is how to call different methods in method viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   if(class A ViewController uses this){
      self.response = // Do request
    }

    if(class b ViewController uses this){
      self.response = // Do another request
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?? It would be better if you give more explanation .Have If else check on viewDidLoad for loading different data .

Comment: Problem is how to detect if my `CustomTableViewController` is used by ViewController A, ot ViewController B. I added some details to question

Comment: u cant have two controllers in a controller unless u r using container view controller. U need to provide more info. What type of data r u looking into. How u r trying to load the data ?

Comment: I have two ViewController in application. Both of these are loaded the semiliar datas. I want to use one tableViewController class to display data, that does not make dublicate table class

Comment: So you have 2 instances of the same `CustomTableViewController` class, contained within 2 different VC classes? If it is properly abstract, it shouldn't matter what its parent view is. It should load whatever data it's told to load. `viewDidLoad` for the *different* viewController classes can be different. `viewDidLoad` for the tableView should only be concerned about handling its own stuff. If the data is so different that the tables need to be unique, create 2 custom `tableViewCell` classes. If the data displayed in both cases has a similar format, work on improving your class design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one.

Add an inspectable property to `CustomTableViewController`, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBInspectable NSString *dataSetName;
```

By declaring it `IBInspectable`, you're telling Xcode to let you set the property directly in the storyboard when you select the controller in the document outline:

[image: storyboard editor]

Now you can type “A” or “B” in the “Data Set Name” field. In `viewDidLoad`, you can check it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if ([self.dataSetName isEqualToString:@"A"]) {
        [self loadDataSetA];
    } else {
        [self loadDataSetB];
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution!

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be have custom init for this class and have private property to store the controller like this -

1.Have a instance variable in class like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *controller;

-(instanceType)initWithController:(UIViewController*)controller {
      self = [super init];

   if(self) {
           self.controller = controller;
           }
   return self;
 }
```

2. Now in in your viewDidLoad just check your stored property before loading data like this -

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {

   if( [self.controller isMemberOfClass:[A class]] ) {
       self.response = // Do request
     }
   else if ([self.controller isMemberOfClass:[B class]]) {
        self.response = // Do another request
      }
   }
   ```